# Trigger Lambda function when a new object arrives in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have S3 bucket named 'files'. Every day new file arrives there. Example:

```
/files/data-01-23-2017--11-33am.txt
/files/data-01-24-2017--10-28am.txt
```

How would I make a Lambda function and set a trigger to execute one shell script on EC2 when new file arrives?
Example of new file is:

```
/files/data-01-25-2017--11-43am.txt
```

Command that I would want to execute on EC2 is (with parameter as new file name that just arrived):

```
python /home/ec2-user/jobs/run_job.py data-01-25-2017--11-43am.txt
```

Comment: [EC2 RunCommand](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/run-command.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 can be configured to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created. However, Lambda functions do not have access to your Amazon EC2 instances. It is not an appropriate architecture to use.

**Some alternative options** (these are separate options, not multiple steps):

- Instead of running a command on an Amazon EC2 instance, **put your code in the Lambda function** (no EC2 instance required). *(Best option!)*
- Configure Amazon S3 to **push a message into an Amazon SQS queue**. Have your code on the EC2 instance regularly poll the queue. When it receives a message, process the object in S3.
- Configure Amazon S3 to **send a message to an Amazon SNS topic**. Subscribe an end-point of your application (effectively an API) to the SNS queue, so that it receives a message when a new object has been created.

Comment: Thanks for the options first! Following question regarding first option:
If python code is big (e.g. several hundreds of lines or more) - does it still fit this case scenario?
Also - when it executes - there is nothing about enviroment, mounts etc. that can know in that moment?

Comment: The size of your Python code doesn't matter (much) in Lambda, but execution is limited to 5 minutes and there is only 500MB of space in the `/tmp` directory. You can choose a larger memory size to do more/faster processing (which also increases the CPU allocation). If your situation is "When *this* happens, run *that* code", then Lambda is ideal.

Comment: Note: `several hundreds of lines or more` - that is perfectly okay but a really huge code base (massive libraries) might hit the limit of 250MB of uncompressed code/dependencies allowed. See [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) for details.